# Having an SQL Error or I'm missing a syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem on using this SQL Query

```
DELETE FROM `acc_reg_num_db` t
WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM `acc_reg_num_db` tt
         WHERE t.account_id = tt.account_id
           AND t.key = tt.key
           AND tt.value > t.value)
   AND t.key IN ('#betaminutes', '#online_minute')
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 't WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM acc_reg_num_db tt WHERE t.acco' at
> line 1

Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks

Comment: @NickW, Why do you say that? In MySQL, ` characters are for delimiting identifers. Whereas ' characters are for delimiting string literals.

Comment: @ChanchanDeGuzman, You are using `key` as a column name, but that's a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K). You need to enclose reserved words in back-ticks if you want to use them as column names.

Comment: @BillKarwin still error. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't
WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM `acc_reg_num_db` tt
         WHERE t.`ac' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL requires that you list the table being deleted from.  And, you cannot re-use the table being deleted from.  So, try this:

```
DELETE arn
    FROM `acc_reg_num_db` arn JOIN
         (SELECT account_id, key, MAX(value) as max_value
          FROM acc_reg_num_db arn2
          GROUP BY account_id, key
         ) arn2
         USING (account_id, key)
    WHERE arn.value < arn2.max_value AND
          arn.key IN ('#betaminutes', '#online_minute');
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response,
Unfortunately I have an error again which says

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, MAX(value) as max_value
          FROM acc_reg_num_db arn2
          GROU' at line 3

I want to delete all of each's account_id's keys but will leave 1 with the highest value for key for each account_id

Comment: @ChanchanDeGuzman . . . `key` is a reserved word.  I figured you knew this and was just simplifying your column names for the question.  You should change the name to.a non-keyword.  In the meantime, you have to escape the name when you use it.

Comment: Hi again. Im actually quite new to this SQL Query and I really dont know how will I do this.

Comment: I was able to mass delete the betaminutes and online_minute now. I escaped the key by adding it in the `key`. Now my problem is, how do I delete duplicate entries?

Comment: @ChanchanDeGuzman . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with examples of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues here:

- You cannot alias the table `acc_reg_num_db` you are deleting from
- You cannot delete from the table you are selecting from in the subquery -> you need a derived table

Assuming there is an `id` column, this is what you need:

```
DELETE FROM `acc_reg_num_db`
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM `acc_reg_num_db` t
        WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM `acc_reg_num_db` tt
            WHERE t.account_id = tt.account_id
            AND t.key = tt.key
            AND tt.value > t.value)
            AND t.key IN ('#betaminutes', '#online_minute')
    ) as x
)
;
```

Also, `key` and `value` are reserved SQL keywords and you should avoid using them in column names

Comment: Hi thank you for your response,
#1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
I do not have an 'id" column.
I only have 4 columns on my acc_reg_num_db table
account_id, key, index, value
I forgot to add in a primary key on that table so I want to delete all of each's account_id's keys but will leave 1 with the highest value for key for each account_id

Comment: You are welcome, can you please accept it as the correct answer if it fits your needs

Comment: Im still having error with the code above.
It says, #1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'. Can you help me with this? Thanks

Comment: you need to replace `id` with whatever the name of your primary key is

Comment: I actually dont have a primary key. I have 4 columns. account_id, key, index, value I forgot to add in a primary key on that table so I want to delete all of each's account_id's keys but will leave 1 with the highest value for key for each account_id